# Selecting Order button using selenium python did not work

Tags: python, selenium

For the following html, none of the methods below could select the Order button:

Please help!

**Code**

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Order')]").click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name('ui-button-text').click()
```

**HTML**

```
<label class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right" for="order" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text">
        Order
    </span>
</label>
```

Comment: could not locate element...

Comment: If it was Element Not Found, then there's two likely possibilities.  One is to put a pause or wait before the find element.  The other is the element is contained in a `frame` or `iframe`, and you'll need to use `browser.switch_to_frame("frameIdentifier")`

Comment: @Richard have already applied for pause but no sucess, will test for browser.switch_to_frame("frameIdentifier")

Comment: You'll need to examine the HTML to see if the `span` is contained in a `frame` or `iframe`.

Comment: @Richard how can I know that?

Comment: @Richard NoSuchFrameException: Message: u'Unable to locate frame: frameIdentifier' for browser.switch_to_frame("frameIdentifier")

Comment: @Richard Thinking that it can be catched through label class, but how?

Comment: @julie, Richard did not mean "frameIdentifier" literally - he meant for you to replace it with your own. You need to start digging and debugging this yourself. We don't know this web page, you do - because you've shared very few lines with us and you've got the whole thing at your disposal - you'll need to do some of the work too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.ui-button > span.ui-button-text').click()
```

The above will locate element whose parent class is `ui-button` and its own class is `ui-button-text`.

You can also specify multiple classes through cssSelectors as follows :

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.ui-button.ui-button-text-only > span.ui-button-text').click()
```